# I am using the following code for updating the table in mysql database. It ain't working

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

```
$query = "update admin set username = $username and password = $password where id = 1;
```

Any alternative to use this code with php?

Comment: admin - table name, username and password are the field name and $username and $password are values to be assigned in each field.

Comment: No error checking whatsoever.

Comment: how to use this code in php?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes around the variables.

Try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE admin SET username = '".$username."', password = '".$password."' WHERE id = 1";
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: It worked. Thank you.